# When using Unity 5, is there a way to print/save/identify the last n lines of code that were executed at a specific point?

Tags: c#, unity, debugging

So, here is what I am after. Is there a way to identify which were the last n lines of code that were executed in Unity 5 (with C#) at a given point of the game?

I know I can use Debug.Break() to set break points to help identifying problematic parts of the code. However, when the codes escalate and multiple functions interact, it is sometimes difficult to identify what came immediately before the break point.

Therefore, my question. Is there a way to retrieve the lines of code that were executed for instance before a break point?

Comment: Errr do you know what a call stack is?

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Yes I know. However, since I can't run code directly in my VS installation )have to run it in Unity directly), the call stack of the VS remains empty.

Comment: Oh ok then, perhaps something useful will come out of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the property [`Environment.StackTrace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.environment.stacktrace%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the current call-stack, i.e. which method called which method which called which method which called this method.

Most debuggers also expose this information in a more comfortable way.

This usually gives you a pretty good picture of what chain of events lead to this line being executed. It won't tell you which path of an if/else was taken before jumping into another method, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So, I've trying `Debug.Log(System.Environment.StackTrace)` to print the stack to the console. However, it only gave the number of the line that made such call:    `at System.Environment.get_StackTrace() in /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Environment.cs:line 227
   at SpatialP+<InspectBVH>c__Iterator0.MoveNext() in C:\Documents\Unity Projects\New Project\Assets\SpatialP.cs:line 613
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<InspectBVH>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/SpatialP.cs:613)`

Comment: @KimShutter What else would you have expected?

Comment: @KimShutter You can often infer which lines executed previously within each function listed, since unless you're using `goto`, control flow doesn't jump about randomly - in many cases you can just work backwards from the given line. If you have a complex sequence of conditional branches preceding the lines where your stack trace capture is triggered then you'll likely need to instrument those yourself or use a debugger to step through the execution.

Comment: @DMGregory That's exactly my case and that's precisely what I was expecting: I mean, as I've stated, the reason why I asked for a way to retrieve the last N lines of code executed was, as I said, because I have intricate code functions that may call each other. So, just knowing where the break was called is not enough: and by the way, that alone is useless, because as I said, that is just a matter of including `Debug.Break()` in Unity's code. What I need is precisely to know the lines that were executed before that.